# Elementary Probability Stirzaker : Ex 1.12 Family Planning

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

My question is regarding $case(b), P(C)$ of the following exercise:

[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMchJ.png)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFq9d.png)

In the above problem solution, when the sample space for $P(C) case (b)$ is reduced to only 4 possible families. The solution has a weird explanation to come to an answer $\frac{1}{2}$. I believe the answer should be $\frac{1}{4}$ as out of the four possible families, there is only one possibility when girls are more than boys i.e $F_1 = G$. Please explain how author reaches a solution of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here first Family F1 = {G}. It means when further cases are derived first G is fixed.

Further cases are F1 = {GBG, GBB, GGB, GGG}

As you can see there are 2 cases out of 4 where girls are more than boy.

So probability = $\frac 2{4} = \frac 1{2}$

Comment: I don't believe this to be true or I may be interpreting it wrong. If you are going to have one girl or three babies, stopping which ever is sooner - I will stop when I have the first girl. My sample space would like like this ${G, BBB, BBG, BG}$. The probability that there are more girls than boys now would be $\frac{1}{4}$. Do you agree?